# Is it possible to record all executed information for later replay?

Tags: c, debugging, gdb

So i'm debugging a very rare case that SEGSEV occurs, I do not know when it will happen, but i know that when it happens, one local var is `-1`, so I did this in gdb

```
break file.c:100 if t1 == -1
```

the problem is i have to go back many steps to find out what happened, is it possible to record all execution information, so that I can replay the execution?

Comment: You cant record and reply the execution as such but you can record the execution path that was taken during the run using code coverage tools, you can analyze it to see which execution flow leads to issue that you want to debug

Comment: you can use watchpoints in gdb or simply you can log with printf.

Comment: Does https://www.sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/ProcessRecord/Tutorial do what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is currently the [rr project](http://rr-project.org/) for linux which record the execution of your program and help you replay the execution in GDB.

Windows also seem to have some [replay debugging capabilities with winDbg preview](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/windbg/2017/09/25/time-travel-debugging-in-windbg-preview/)

Comment: Links are good, but please elaborate your answer a little bit.